# Flutter: Hot restart crashes the app but cold restart doesn't (because a recorder is already initialized)

Tags: flutter, restart, recorder, hot-reload

I am using the flutter_sound package to record some audio and as soon as the app starts up I initialise a recorder.
When I hot restart the app another recorder is initialised and the app crashes because on iOS there can only be one recorder.

When I cold restart the app I don't run into this problem, probably because all the resources are freed.
How can I make sure that the code that releases the recorder is called whenever I hot restart the app?

This is the relevant code in the UI.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<RecorderService>(
          create: (_) => RecorderService(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: ScreenToShow(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is the relevant code in the Recorder Service class:

```
class RecorderService with ChangeNotifier {
  Recording recording;
  RecordingStatus status = RecordingStatus.uninitialized;
  static const String RECORDING_FORMAT = ".aac";
  static const String LISTENING_FORMAT = ".mp3";
  static const Duration UPDATE_DURATION_OF_STREAM = Duration(milliseconds: 100);

  RecorderService() {
    _initialize();
  }

  /// Private properties
  FlutterSoundRecorder _recorder;
  Directory _tempDir;
  FileConverterService _fileConverterService = FileConverterService();

  /// This is the file path in which the [_recorder] writes its data. From the moment it gets assigned in [_initialize()] it stays fixed
  String _pathToCurrentRecording;

  /// This is the file path to which the [recording] will be saved to. It changes with every call of [_startWithoutReset()]
  String _pathToSavedRecording;

  /// This function can only be executed once per session else it crashes on iOS (because there is already an initialized recorder)
  /// So when we hot restart the app this makes it crash
  _initialize() async {
    try {
      /// The arguments for [openAudioSession] are explained here: https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_sound/blob/master/doc/player.md#openaudiosession-and-closeaudiosession
      _recorder = await FlutterSoundRecorder().openAudioSession(
          focus: AudioFocus.requestFocusAndKeepOthers,
          category: SessionCategory.playAndRecord,
          mode: SessionMode.modeDefault,
          audioFlags: outputToSpeaker);
      await _recorder.setSubscriptionDuration(UPDATE_DURATION_OF_STREAM);
      _tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      _pathToSavedRecording =
          "${_tempDir.path}/saved_recording$LISTENING_FORMAT";
      status = RecordingStatus.initialized;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Recorder service could not be initialized because of error = $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  dispose() async {
    try {
      await _recorder?.closeAudioSession();
      super.dispose();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Recorder service could not be disposed because of error = $e");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you properly closing the session. Read the documentation from [here](https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_sound/blob/master/doc/recorder.md#flutter-sound-recorder-api)

Comment: Yes, I am closing the session when the widget is disposed. But if you hot restart the app no widget is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this is a month past your initial post but I came across this problem today.

I've found that the fix is to not call the following within the `initState()` of the page:

```
_recorder = await FlutterSoundRecorder().openAudioSession(...)
```

Instead, I created the following:

```
Future<void> startAudioSession() async {recorderModule.openAudioSession(...);}
```

And called it at the beginning of the `startRecorder` function, and then used the `closeAudioSession()` in the `stopRecorder` function.